# The button size change when background image url change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

Currently I have a button

```
<input id="fireAction" type="button" class="submit" onclick="disableSubmit('preFlight');"><br>
```

Then I change the background image of the button in different case

eg.

```
#('#fireAction').css('background-image','url(fail.jpg)');
#('#fireAction').css('background-image','url(success.jpg)');
```

However, since the size of fail.jpg / success.jpg is not the same, how to define some css (Tried width:auto but not working) to make the button fit the size according to the size of background image? thanks

Comment: Please post a functional example that illustrates your problem on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: If you are using CSS3 you can add "background-size" to set the same size to both background images.

Comment: if you are changing the `background-image`, might as well change the `width`? Alternatively, you could have 2 separate classes `.fail` and `.success` and you could toggle these using jQuery

Comment: Add a class on your button .Please refer the below URL.


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1733006/css-force-image-width-and-height-without-stretching

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know whether you are looking for JS, jQuery or CSS answer, but as far as CSS goes, you cannot resize the element based on the `background-image`, what you can do is, you can use `input type=image` here

```
<input type="image" src="#" alt="Image" />
```

Or if you want to stick with JavaScript or jQuery, than declare 2 classes with custom width's and toggle them as per your requirement