# How can I set the size of logos the same via CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, background-image, image-resizing

The images are all of the same sizes.
I use Image GIF and the size of the images on the hard disk is 415x72.

The images are placed in a table I want to make all images the same via css.

Images details on the hard disk:
[image]

view.jsp:

```
<%
logo ="<img src='/path/images/vendor/"+vendor.toLowerCase()+".gif' style='max-width:120px'/>";
%>

<liferay-ui:search-container-column-text name='vendor'
         cssClass="width-10" value="<%=logo%>" />
```

Image details:

[image]

I've looked into this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19414856/how-can-i-make-all-images-of-different-height-and-width-the-same-via-css), but doesn't work for me. I couldn't get any solution to work to my requirement.

I tried this code below but the picture becomes blurry.

```
.img {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width:  100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-repeat:   no-repeat;
    background-size:     cover;
}
```

view.jsp:

```
<%
logo ="<img class='img' src='/path/images/vendor/"+vendor.toLowerCase()+".gif' style='max-width:120px'/>";
%>
```

Images details after adding the code:

[image: details after adding the codes]

Is there a solution with the css or I have to use a software for image?

The requested result image of same size and clear:

[requested result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vjl9m.png)

#### Update:

1- I tried to change the width and set the height to auto but I did not get what I want.

2- I tried this line but did not work.

```
<%
logo = "<div class='img' style='background-image:url(\""+logoUrl+"\");' style='max-width:220px;'>&nbsp;</div>";
%>
```

3- I tried to resize with html tag `<img>` and to cut with `background-image`.
I followed this link: [CSS Display an Image Resized and Cropped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493296/css-display-an-image-resized-and-cropped) I did not got a good result.

```
<%    
logo = "<div class='crop'><img class='img' src='"+logoUrl+"' style='max-width:120px;' alt='"+vendor.toLowerCase()+"'/></div>";
%>
```

css:

```
.crop {
    width: 160px;
    height: 120px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.crop img {
    width: 565px;
    height: auto;
    margin: -75px 0 0 -100px;
}
```

Details images:

[Images with 128x128 size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YXvNr.png)

From the outside the images are the same size but from the inside they are not the same size. I want images with the same height and width without modifying the aspect ratio of the images. How can I do that?

Comment: What size do you want them?

Comment: The css code you have tried doesn't work because your image doesn't have a class `img`

Comment: @Coffeebean I want an acceptable size and it is all the same size. Is there a solution with the css or I have to use a software for image?

Comment: @ovokuro I added the class img check the update.

Comment: You are changing the aspect ratio of the images by setting the height and the width to the same size. That is why they are squashed. just change the width and set the height to auto

Comment: @Coffeebean do I have to convert .GIF to .SVG and what exactly should I do?

Comment: @Coffeebean I want a result like that checked the update. Is it possible?

Comment: @Coffeebean pls check the requested result. I tried to change the width and set the height to auto but I did not get what I want.

Answer (score 3):

Css :

```
.image-container { 
    width:300px;
    height:150px;
    text-align:center;
}

.image-container img {
    height:100%;
}
```

Html:

```
<div class="image-container">
    <img src="path"/>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but it did not work. the images are not of the same size and are blurry. check the requested result.

Comment: Html code must be: <div class="image-container"><img src="path"/></div>

Comment: a `<div>` inside a `<td>` did not work. The logos are placed in a table. Check this [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1110915/is-a-div-inside-a-td-a-bad-idea).

Answer (score -1):

```css
#logo img {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  max-height: 50px;
  max-width: 200px;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-repeat:   no-repeat;
  background-size:     contain;
}
```

```html
 <div id="logo">
<img src="https://99designs-blog.imgix.net/blog/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/amazon-logo-16x9jpg.jpg?auto=format&q=60&fit=max&w=930" alt="logo" />                   
</div>
```

Comment: Please explain your answer. Never assume that everyone knows what it is that you did