# Display image in flexbox side by side and same size?

Tags: html, css, jsp, flexbox

I have put the images side by side successfully but it ends up with different sizes using flexbox

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kt7Qq.png)

I'm hoping for some help which can display the image with same size in a same row.

CSS CODE

```
<style>
        *{
            margin:0;
            padding: 0;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        .row{
            padding-top: 50px;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            flex-wrap:wrap;
            justify-content: space-around;
        }
        .product{
            flex-basis:25%;
            margin: 5px;
            padding:5px;
            max-width: 200px;
            margin-bottom: 50px;
            transition: transform 0.5s;
        }
        .product:hover {
            transform: translateY(-5px);
        }
        .pro-con {
            background-color: #3369FF;
        }
        .row>img{
            height: 100%;
            width:auto;
            transition: transform 0.5s;
        }
        h2{
            text-align: center;
        }
        p{
            color:black;
            text-align: center;
        }

    </style>
```

HTML

```
<body>

<h1 style="text-align: center">ALL PRODUCTS</h1>

<%
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/users", "root","123456767");
    Statement stm = conn.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = stm.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM users.product\n");

    int cnt = 1;
    while(rs.next())
    {
        ++ cnt;
        if(cnt % 2 == 0)
        {
%>

<div class="row">
    <div class="product">
        <div class="pro-con">
        <a href="Bdetail.jsp?pid=<%=rs.getString("product_id")%>">
        <img src="./ProductDisplayServlet?product_id=<%=rs.getString("product_id")%>"/>
        </a>
        <h2><%=rs.getString("product_name")%></h2>
        <p><%=rs.getString("price")%></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <%
    }
    else {
    %>
    <div class="product">
        <div class="pro-con">
        <a href="Bdetail.jsp?pid=<%=rs.getString("product_id")%>">
        <img src="./ProductDisplayServlet?product_id=<%=rs.getString("product_id")%>"/>
        </a>
        <h2><%=rs.getString("product_name")%></h2>
        <p><%=rs.getString("price")%></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <%
            }
    </div>
    }
    %>
</body>
```

I'm hoping for any help as I'm hoping to display 4 images of different sizes in a row yet they can display in different sizes. Any tutorial or help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It would help a lot if you could attach a [Minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) along with the things you have tried to solve the problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I make all images of different height and width the same via CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19414856/how-can-i-make-all-images-of-different-height-and-width-the-same-via-css)

Comment: No, it remains the same :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `background-image` property and fixed-width containers for this.

```css
.img-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  padding-top: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: none;
  background-position: center;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.card {
  width: 100px;
  margin: 0 10px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px black solid;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="img-wrapper" style="background-image: url('https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/adfffc')"></div>
    Card 1
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="img-wrapper" style="background-image: url('https://dummyimage.com/400x600/000/fff')"></div>
    Card 2
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="img-wrapper" style="background-image: url('https://dummyimage.com/1300x200/000/ffabff')"></div>
    Card 3
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, this ensures all of the images are in a fixed-width container. If the container (or the `.card` class) were to increase in width, the images would increase proportionally due to the `padding-top: 100%;` property. This property is based on the width of the container.

> This essentially means that it will increase the height of the container as the width increases, making it a square/1:1 aspect-ratio

If you wish to fit the image inside of the `.img-wrapper` container, you can replace `background-size: cover` with `background-size: contain` instead.