# Bootstrap each card instance images are different height

Tags: image, bootstrap-5, angular-ui-bootstrap, image-size

I am coding an angular project and am using bootstrap 5.
I am having an issue with `card-img-top`, as for every image the user uploads that is a different resolution, the image height is different. I need to achieve that every image has the same width and height ratio or whatever as every other one.
For instance: https://carsandbids.com/ has the desired look

Below I have provided code for a card.component.html file and its parent component.
card.component.html

```
<div class="card h-100 content-container">
    <img src="{{auction?.imagePath}}" alt="Item Image" class="card-img-top img-fluid">
    <div class="card-body p-0">
        <div class="my-4">
            <h5 class="card-title m-0 p-0">{{auction?.title}}</h5>
            <p class="card-text"><span class="badge badge-primary m-0" *ngIf="auction?.noReserve">No Reserve</span>
                {{auction?.discription}}</p>
            <p class="card-text text-muted m-0 p-0">{{auction?.location}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the parent component file

```
<main class="live-auctions col">
  <div class="auction-container">
    <div class="auction-thumbnail row g-2" *ngIf="liveAuctions != undefined && liveAuctions.length != 0">
      <app-auction-card *ngFor="let auction of liveAuctions" [auction]="auction"></app-auction-card>
    </div>
    <div class="no-auctions" *ngIf="liveAuctions == undefined || liveAuctions.length == 0">
      <p class="text-center text-muted">No Auctions Available</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Tried various solutions, tried h-auto, h-100, img-fluid, img-thumbnail

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I make all images of different height and width the same via CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19414856/how-can-i-make-all-images-of-different-height-and-width-the-same-via-css)

Comment: the object-fit:cover; attribute cuts some of the images