# How to target image props in css

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Assume that This is my parent (Cards) component -

```
import React from 'react'
import './Cards.css';
import Mycard from './Cardshown';
import image1 from '../../Images/project.png';
import image2 from '../../Images/robot.png';
const Cards = () => {
  return (
        <div className="img-section">
            <Mycard img={image1} name={"Hello"} detail={"I am a Developer"}/>
            <Mycard img={image2} name={"Hii"} detail={"I am a Coder"}/>
        </div>
  )
}

export default Cards
```

and here is the child (Cardshown) component -

```
import React from 'react'
import './Cardshown.css';
const Cardshown = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className='cards-shown'>
      <img src={props.img} alt="#" />
      <span>{props.name}</span>
      <span>{props.detail}</span>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Cardshown
```

I want to render different images through props which are different in size(height-width). But when I run the code those images are completely messed up.

I tried with

> transform : scale(1)

property in CSS with img attribute but it's not working.

So is there any process through which I can modify the size of those images differently without croping those images?

here is two images I like to add - [image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJEaW.png) & [image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ek0zU.png)

Specifically, I want to ask if there is any process to target the props in CSS or if we can modify the size of these images differently using JavaScript or CSS.

Comment: So you want your images to have the same width/height (or both) or do you want to have them stay the size they already have?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I make all images of different height and width the same via CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19414856/how-can-i-make-all-images-of-different-height-and-width-the-same-via-css)

Comment: _"I tried with `transform : scale(1)` property in CSS with img attribute but it's not working."_ - that says, "scale the element to the exact size it already has" (because of the factor 1), so how could that _possibly_ achieve anything.

Comment: @PatrickCerny I want to have the same size and width for all images but also want to style the images differently so that if I need to change one image I can do that without changing other images.

Comment: @CBroe I just tested it with the transform property, but as all images are not in the same size & so this goes messed up. images caught that 1-factor size but for different sizes, images look like they are not In same size. Some images are bigger and some fit perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I read from your comment, you wan't to style your child component independently from your other components. Theres 2 way to do that

## 1. Pass classnames

You could add a "classname" property to your child component, which then will be applied to your parent. This way you pass the styles indirectly to the child component.

```js
import React from 'react'
import './Cards.css';
import Mycard from './Cardshown';
import image1 from '../../Images/project.png';
import image2 from '../../Images/robot.png';
const Cards = () => {
  return (
        <div className="img-section">
            <Mycard 
               img={image1} 
               name="Hello" 
               detail="I am a Developer"/>
            <Mycard 
               img={image2} 
               name="Hi"
               classname="scale" 
               detail="I am a Developer too"/>
           
        </div>
  )
}

export default Cards
```

Your child would apply these styles like this.

```js
import React from 'react'
import './Cardshown.css';
const Cardshown = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className={`cards-shown ${classname}`}>
      <img src={props.img} alt="#" />
      <span>{props.name}</span>
      <span>{props.detail}</span>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Cardshown
```

in your css you could do following:

```css
.scale{
  scale: 1.1;
}
```

## 2. Pass a style object

You also could pass a style object, which will apply the styles directly to the element (not really pretty)

```js
import React from 'react'
import './Cards.css';
import Mycard from './Cardshown';
import image1 from '../../Images/project.png';
import image2 from '../../Images/robot.png';
const Cards = () => {
  return (
        <div className="img-section">
            <Mycard 
               img={image1} 
               name="Hello" 
               detail="I am a Developer"/>
            <Mycard 
               img={image2} 
               name="Hi"
               style={{scale: 1.1}}
               detail="I am a Developer too"/>
           
        </div>
  )
}

export default Cards
```

Your child would apply these styles like this.

```js
import React from 'react'
import './Cardshown.css';
const Cardshown = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className="cards-shown" style={props.style ?? {}}>
      <img src={props.img} alt="#" />
      <span>{props.name}</span>
      <span>{props.detail}</span>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Cardshown
```

#### **Note that this is just a example. This WILL scale your entire div, so be aware of that**

It also seems that you are struggling with styling your images in general. Try to giving your images a class and styling them with the `width` property.

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion @patrick. It's really helpful.I am new to ReactJS and all web development. So, accidentally or better say logically I thought about it and later I found exactly what you have said in your second suggestion. I added the style prop and target in my img tag in the child component.yes, what you have done is exactly what I have done but the difference is I called prop in img tag not in the div tag like this -
`<img src={props.Projectimg} style={props.style01} alt="#" />`

and in parent component I just added this - `style01={{transform : "scale(0.5)"}}`

Comment: @Randomdev. so did it work? Please accept the answer if yes, if not please provide further information so the world after you may have it documented :)

Answer (score 0):

The thing is when you use images as props and you want to style those images independently you have to use props again. In my case -

```
<Mycard img={image1} style01={{transform:scale(0.6)}} name={"Hello"} detail={"I am a Developer"}/>
<Mycard img={image2} style01={{transform:scale(1)}} name={"Hii"} detail={"I am a Coder"}/>
```

I use style01 prop and inside that I give a value of transform scale. Then I called prop like this -

```
<img src={props.Projectimg} style={props.style01} alt="#" />
```

In that way I can modify every single image independently also later on I will add width property in the same way to scale those images properly.