# Dealing with multiple images of differing height/width

Tags: html, css, image-processing

I have been sent numerous logos of numerous heights and widths (some very tall, others wide with minimal height) that need displaying in table/grid.

Is there a way of setting them all a certain height/width without causing distortion or the images to be chopped off.

Hopefully looking at a CSS solution but even a piece of software that may help.

Answer (score 0):

As you want CSS solution so this may be helpful as it will make your images of same height and width.

```
 <div id="logo"><img src="image.jpg"></div>
    #logo { position: relative; height: 100px; width: 200px; }
    #logo img { position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; }
```

This way you will be showing same images from top and left portion of your image.

This code is taken from another solution, here is full URL to that solution [[How to set an image's width and height without stretching it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1733006/css-force-image-width-and-height-without-stretching][1])

[1]: [How to set an image's width and height without stretching it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1733006/css-force-image-width-and-height-without-stretching) Hope that works for you