# What's <img> tag's css property to display images without distortion?

Tags: html, css, image

this question might seem quite odd, but here's the deal:

I met some article the other day that and saw `<img>` tag's css picture display properties, which allowed to change tag's width and height, without stretching the picture itself.

The final effect looked like `overflow: hidden;`, but without parent container.

I forgot to bookmark that article and property name. Can someone tell me the property description?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS: force image width and height without stretching](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1733006/css-force-image-width-and-height-without-stretching)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess you are looking for [object-fit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit) CSS property.

```css
img {
    width: 100px;
    height: 200px;
  }
img.noStretch{
    object-fit: cover;
  }
```

```html
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200"/>

<img class="noStretch" src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You may need a wrapper, or use background style instead.

For my sugesstion:

```css
#img {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 160px;
  height: 120px;
  background: 50% 50% no-repeat;
  background-size: cover; /* try also: contain or 100% */
}
```

```html
<div id="img" style="background-image: url(https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/0217df290e6f29cbe204479f48fb662f?d=identicon&r=PG)"></div>
```

I think it would be what you want.

Comment: Yes, that gives the same effect, as `object-fit` property, described above, and supported in all browser, but I was looking for one-property solution.